# Attempting to install Steam, Software Centre missing?

Tags: kde, steam

You guys were very helpful last week in my quest to download Steam. I am operating Ubuntu on my Toshiba Chromebook 2 and had Football Manager downloaded and was all good until my girlfriend this morning has managed to reset my computer so I am now back to square one and need of some help.

I have just reinstalled Crouton on the KDE display, but it appears that the software centre is nowhere to be found. I have tried the prompt;

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

But I am greeted with the message

sudo:

```
 apt-get: command not found
```

I promised my friends I'd have it installed today and they're all round my house today for a gaming session so if I can get this resolved I'll be grateful, you're already legends in my eyes. Cheers.

Matt.

Comment: @Zacharee1 - Can you help my friend, you sorted me out proper last week.

Comment: First, Kubuntu uses Muon as a software center. Second, if apt-get was not found, your girlfriend somehow managed to wreck your system. I recommend reinstalling (and talking to her).

Comment: She knocked the OS out of developer mode, I've talked to her alright but it's Valentines day you know how it is.

Comment: Excuse me for my rookieness, but what are the commands for a reinstall?

Comment: Bascially creating a bootable USB with an iso of UBUNTU. Boot into the live-OS and chose to reinstall. It is the same as installing it the first time.

Comment: I don't have experience with Chromebooks + Ubuntu. As far as I know, to install Ubuntu on a Chromebook you basically get Ubuntu's userland and chroot into it while using Chrome OS's kernel, using this Crouton thing. So you'll probably want to wipe Ubuntu out and do the whole process again. Sorry, there's no command to reinstall. And, by the way, "resetting" an Ubuntu system is not that simple, and if apt-get is no more then everything is pretty wrecked now.

Comment: @HATEthePLOT Not the case with Chromebooks. Ubuntu for chromebooks doesn't use its own kernel. It's basically a chroot environment.

Comment: reinstalled and apt-get is present in /usr/bin/

Comment: My status is name: precise
encrypted: no
Entering /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...
crouton: version 1-20160206234800~master:daa872a0
release: precise
architecture: amd64
xmethod: xorg
targets: kde
host: version 7647.73.0 (Official Build) stable-channel swanky 
kernel: Linux localhost 3.10.18 #1 SMP Sun Jan 24 13:09:58 PST 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
freon: yes

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to know how the PC was resetted and what has been done exactly. As far my reserach (googeling) braught me: [Terminal: sudo: apt-get: command not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491374/terminal-sudo-apt-get-command-not-found) suggest a clean reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Something went wrong with your installation. try to locate apt-get. it should be in /usr/bin/apt-get/. If not, see if the file is actually there. Then check the $PATH: echo $PATH.
Is /usr/bin/ completely empty? In that case, your only option is to reinstall Ubuntu. Or is there just no file apt-get? Then download and manually install the apt package, as follows: look at your /etc/apt/sources.list to find the correct mirror, then go to that mirror, to the pool/main/a/apt/ directory, download the correct .deb file for your architecture, and install it with `sudo dpkg -i apt-xxx.deb`

If you have too many empty folders(/home etc...) then better to reinstall Ubuntu all over again.